# How to change text from in HTML Label from backend

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm starting to learn ASP.NET Core MVC and just found out that the toolbox is inaccessible/disabled/grayed out, so in html I cannot use `<asp:Label/>` tag and have to use `<label></label>` tag instead.

Now I am having trouble changing the string on the HTML Tag `<label></label>` from the backend.

For this case I already wrote `runat="server"` inside the tag but still an error occured that says:

> The name 'lblkpj' does not exist in the current context

Here is the example html:

```
<label class="text-center mb-1 fw-bold" runat="server" id="lblkpj"> </label>
```

and C#:

```
if (tbl.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    lblkpj.text = "Success";
}
else
{
    lblkpj.text = "Failed";
}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Work with [Razor markup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

You can implement the logic in View by declaring the variable. And use `@` symbol. Razor will evaluate the expression and render the output into HTML.

And make sure that you need to return the ViewModel as a `List` of your model objects from the Controller to View.

> View

```
@model List<YourModel>
@{
  string status = Model.Rows.Count > 0 ? "Success" : "Failed";
}

<label class="text-center mb-1 fw-bold" id="lblkpj">@status</label>
```

> Controller

```cs
public class YourController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult YourView()
    {
        // Mock data
        List<YourModel> list = new List<YourModel>();

        return View(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can i ask again, what should i fill on <YourModel> tag?

Comment: `YourModel` is the class in which you create the class definition to store the object instance. Replace the `YourModel` word with the name of class that you used. For your reading, [Strongly-typed data (viewmodel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/overview?view=aspnetcore-6.0#strongly-typed-data-viewmodel)